# How to change the storage location of docker images on a chromebook?

Tags: docker, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Can I change the storage location of Docker images from /var/lib/docker to /mnt/chromeos/removable/SD/docker on my chromebook?

Comment: Either mount your removable drive to `/var/lib/docker` directly (`mount /dev/yourusb /var/lib/docker`) or bind mount it from your mounted location `mount --rbind /mnt/chromeos/removable/SD/docker /var/lib/docker`

Answer (score 0):

The so called docker data graph can be change by modifying the configuration file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like:

```json
{
    "data-root" : "/my/custom/data/graph/path"
}
```